# Remove the auto-added document icon using Notion Enhancer

Tags: css

A question for the Notion Enhancer experts.

Notion autonmatically adds a document icon in the database views when a value has an underlying page. Is there a way using Notion Enhancer and css to remove this icon by default? Any code suggestions?

[image: Screenshot]

I played around with some css stylings but I can't find the proper code piece that triggers the adding of the icon.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.